# Error compiling java code with MinGW gcj

Tags: java, gcc, mingw, gcj

Hey,firends,This is my first post.

I'm just begin to using Gcc to compile java,and I have some trouble in doing this.

My input and output:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception    {
        BufferedReader stdin =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = stdin.readLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

cmd:gcj Porgram.java

<2>output:

***E:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingw32.a:main.c:<.text+0xd2>:undefined reference to '_WinMain@16' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status***

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Ouch. Your formatting got destroyed there. Indent all of your code by four spaces (just select it all and press the 'code' formatting button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gcj neds to be told which of the classes it is compiling contains the main method. You can do this by using the `--main` command line parameter:

```
gcj --main=Program Program.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell gcj the name of the class with the main method:

gcj --main=Program Program.java